# jQuery: How to get the data value after Ajax call

Tags: jquery

I have read a few of the other questions on this and I still could not figure out how to get this to work.

I have this function making the ajax call:

```
    function validateDataPoint(newDataPoint) {
        var $form = $(this).parents('form');
        var $formAction = $form.attr('action');
        var $validationResult;

        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/DataPoints/ValidateNewDataPointBeforeSaving",
            data: newDataPoint
        });

        return $validationResult;
    }
```

And this is how I am calling it from within another function:

```
        var validationRequest = validateDataPoint(newDataPoint);
        validationResult = validationRequest.success(function (data) {
            return data.Urn;
        });
```

And then within the same function I want to test the value of validationResult since data.Urn will either have a string value of "Success" or "Failed" in relation to the processing that is completed on the server side.

So here is the code below:

```
        //post the Json object to the server to validate and get the result
        var validationRequest = validateDataPoint(newDataPoint);
        validationResult = validationRequest.success(function (data) {
            return data.Urn;
        });

        //based on the result give the thumbs-up or thumbs-down
        if (validationResult == "Success") {
            resultFlag = "<span class='badge badge-success'><i class='icon-thumbs-up icon-white'></i></span>";
        }
        else if (validationResult == "Failed") {
            resultFlag = "<span class='badge badge-important'><i class='icon-thumbs-down icon-white'></i></span>";
        }
        else {
            resultFlag = "<span class='badge badge-warning'></span>";
        }
```

**So the question is**...

When I try to access the value of validationResult.responseText I get an undefined error. Basically I want to assign the value of data.Urn to validationResult but I just can't get this to work. If I alert(validationResult); I get [object Object] and then if I alert(validationResult); I get undefined.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's ajax function works in an asynchronous way. Your checks for `validationResult` are taking place, before the ajax has actually finished.

Why don't put them in a callback?

```
validationResult = validationRequest.success(function (data) {
    processResponse(data.Urn);
});

function processResponse(validationResult)
{
    //based on the result give the thumbs-up or thumbs-down
    if (validationResult == "Success") {
        resultFlag = "<span class='badge badge-success'><i class='icon-thumbs-up icon-white'></i></span>";
    }
    else if (validationResult == "Failed") {
        resultFlag = "<span class='badge badge-important'><i class='icon-thumbs-down icon-white'></i></span>";
    }
    else {
        resultFlag = "<span class='badge badge-warning'></span>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try something similar to this. The problem I then had was getting the value of resultFlag to use later on in the same function. So using your example I would end up with:

`validationResult = validationRequest.success(function (data) {
    processResponse(data.Urn);
});

need to begin using the value of resultFlag here`

Comment: Well, this is the nature of an asynchronous approach. You will have to deal with this. Other than that, you theoretically could change the ajax request to being synchronous  with `async: false` but this is not recommended - see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: As it turns out the approach I was taking to solve this problem was just plain wrong. I was looping through an array and building up a table to display the rows of data and then just dumping out the entire string of the table into a dom element. So I threw the code into the bin and started again. This time, I decided to use templates using the mustache.js library and then use the jQuery $.append function to append the new tr to the table. All of this was done within validationResult and now everything is working as expected and with a lot fewer lines of code.